# How to convert all the contents of a list to individual strings to pass as a parameter in dataframe.select()?

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark

My requirement is to pass the list of all column names as a parameter in `dataframe.select(columns)`

1. First of all I am using `dataframe.columns` to get me the list of
   all the columns. Which I am storing as `list1=(dataframe.columns)`
2. Secondly I am using ***.join*** to convert my
   list of columns in strings like - (`strList1 = "','".join(list1)`) which gives me the following output

   > col1','col2','col3','col4

   As you see there is some missing single quotes at the start & end of the string
3. To rectify `strList1` i use f-string formatting as follows -
   `strList2 = f"{strList1}'"`which gives me the following output

   > 'col1','col2','col3','col4'

**The main problem:**

When you pass `strList2` as a parameter in `dataframe.select(strList2)` gives me the following error

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o5813.select. :
> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve
> '*backquote*`col1','col2','col3','col4'`*backquote*'
> given input columns: [
> col1, col2, db.table.col4,
> db.table.col3];; 'Project
> ['col1','col2','col3','col4']

*Note - There is a backquote before col1 and after col4*

I don't understand why the `select` function isn't taking a proper string value / variable (`strList2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string `"'col1','col2','col3','col4'"` to `df.select`. There is no such column called `"'col1','col2','col3','col4'"`, therefore `df.select("'col1','col2','col3','col4'")` will result in an error.

Instead of passing that string, what you need to do is to pass in a list of strings of column names to `df.select`. `df.columns` is already that list (e.g. `['col1', 'col2']`), so you can simply do `df.select(df.columns)`.

In fact, if you simply want to show all columns, you can do `df.select('*')`.

Comment: Hey @mck thanks for the help, basically when i was sending the list as a parameter it throws this error - TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

But the second ans that you gave - df.select('*') worked like a charm. Thanks for that!

Comment: Ah, you may be using an old version of Spark. Then you could also try `df.select(*df.columns)` in order to unpack the list.